# SQL slowness when doing ActiveRecord find on a HABTM relationship

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm running Rails 2.3.5 with a MySQL database.  I have a HABTM relationship between `Books` and `Users` and am trying to get all users who have a specified list of books (defined by an array of book names).

I'm able to perform a `find` call that retrieves this list of users:

```
User.find(
  :all,
  :joins      => :books,
  :conditions => { :books => { :name => book_names } }
)
```

However, this turns out to be extremely slow.  After playing around in SQL, I found that the following call works much faster and retrieves the same results:

```
User.find_by_sql([
  "SELECT users.* FROM users
   INNER JOIN books_users ON users.id = books_users.user_id
   WHERE books_users.book_id IN (SELECT id FROM books WHERE books.name IN (?))",
  book_names
])
```

For the same query, the `find` call takes roughly 3000 ms on my computer whereas the `find_by_sql` call takes roughly 200 ms; this is an entire magnitude of speed difference.  I suspect the culprit has something to do with the fact that the original `find` call is translated into a double `INNER JOIN` SQL query, equivalent to the following:

```
[
  "SELECT users.* FROM users
   INNER JOIN books_users ON users.id = books_users.user_id
   INNER JOIN books ON books_users.book_id = books.id
   WHERE books.name IN (?)",
  book_names
]
```

My questions are:

- Does anyone know why this is the case?  Why is the double `INNER JOIN` slower than my single `INNER JOIN` with a nested `SELECT` query?
- The `find_by_sql` call is not really taking advantage of the built-in support that Rails provides for HABTM relationships.  In particular, it's surfacing the `books_users` join table that the Rails support typically abstracts away from the developer.  Is there a way to specify the same query using a `find` call that hides this?

Comment: Have you created indexes on the `book_id` and `user_id` fields for your `books_users` table?

Comment: Ack... I knew I forgot something.  This was it!  After adding the indexes, the find query now takes 15 ms.

Comment: @dmarkow: add it as an answer, so we can give you the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the comments above, it sounds like you need indexes on your `book_id` and `user_id` fields in `books_users`.

```
class AddIndices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_index :books_users, :book_id
    add_index :books_users, :user_id
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :books_users, :book_id
    remove_index :books_users, :user_id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Does using :include vs. :join do the join better?

```
User.find(
  :all,
  :include    => :books,
  :conditions => { :books => { :name => book_names } }
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately no; it appears to be just as slow.